# Sum into quarter into rows but still display the value

Tags: sql-server

I have output like this below:

[image]

I would like to add in to sum the quarter. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution using [`ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql#group-by-rollup):

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, ValueDate) AS [Year], 
  DATEPART(QUARTER, ValueDate) AS [Quarter],
  99 AS [Month],
  SUM(Value) AS Value 
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '1 ' + [Month] + ' ' + CAST(FY AS VARCHAR(4)), 106) AS ValueDate, Value FROM table_name) AS table_name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(
  DATEPART(YEAR, ValueDate),
  DATEPART(QUARTER, ValueDate)
) HAVING GROUPING(DATEPART(QUARTER, ValueDate)) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  MIN(DATEPART(YEAR, ValueDate)), 
  MIN(DATEPART(QUARTER, ValueDate)), 
  DATEPART(MONTH, ValueDate), 
  SUM(Value)
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '1 ' + [Month] + ' ' + CAST(FY AS VARCHAR(4)), 106) AS ValueDate, Value FROM table_name) AS table_name
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, ValueDate), 
  DATEPART(Month, ValueDate)
ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter], [Month]
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c60702fe75e21661e7ee381033f08e86)